# Extract email addresses from Outlook email body using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using outlook 2000 with a login id in a exchange server of my company.

I have a folder named "undelivered_email" which in under personal folder. I set a rule to move a copy of all the email with title similar to "undelivered email".

Now, how can I loop through all the email in this "undelivered_email" folder, and access the body of each email, then get any email address **inside** the **content body**?

For example, this is a copy of the content of a undelivered email notice:

```
####################################################################
# THIS IS A WARNING ONLY.  YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE. #
####################################################################

Your message could not be delivered for 1 days, 20 hours, 0 minutes.
It will be retried until it is 3 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes old.

For further assistance, please send mail to <postmaster>

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

< abc@xyz.com >: this domain could be reached at this time
```

---

**Well, I don't really need to use vba, any method will do. Should be the easiest one.
I have a lot of such undelivered email notice to handle, I need to extract the email inside. And it would be good if we can export the email list to a file.**

Answer (score 2):

I Googled "outlook vba bounced email" and got some promising hits:

- [MS Access, Outlook: recording bounced email addresses](http://riceball.com/d/content/ms-access-outlook-recording-bounced-email-addresses)
- [Parse email body for email addresses and write them to Excel](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33363)